# Sending custom error message from Express JS over to Backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

In express js, I have the following code which sends a response over to Backbone:

```
if (!user) {
    req.session.messages = [info.message];
    return res.send(400, howCanIsendTheErrorMessageAlso);
}
```

How can I send the error message also, together with the error code?

**How can Backbone receive it?**

Any ideas?

In backbone, I have the following code:

```
loginModel.save({
    username : obj.elEmail.val(),
    password : obj.elPassword.val(),
    admin : false
}, {
    success: function (e) {
        console.log('success');
    }, 
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }   
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout response.send API http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You send it from express with:

```
res.send(500, { error: "hi, there was an error" });
```

In Backbone the parameters of your error callback are: model, xhr, options

So you need to extract your error message fron the xhr object in the error callback like this:

```
obj.save(
   {
    data:"something"
   },
   {
    success: function(model, response, options){
     console.log("worked");
    },
    error: function(model, xhr, options){
     console.log("error", xhr.responseText);
    }
   }
);
```

Comment: Ty, this seems logical and should work, but I cannot make it work on the backbone side. xhr has no responseText

Comment: my express code example was setting the statusText, not the responseText, sorry for that, fixed this via edit.

Comment: send should be replaced in favor of `.status` since `.send` is now depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

in your express app (for example):

```
res.send(403, {
          error: "some elaborate error message"
});
```

Your Backbone code is correct, you'll see the error

regarding error codes, I would recommend sticking to this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes